# Mobile view seems different while using .tk domain. Why?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I hosted my website on the free hosting 000webhost.
Link to my website -->http://daviscomuj.000webhostapp.com/

I used .tk free domain and redirected it to my website hosted on 000webhostapp
Link to my .tk domain-->http://daviscomuj.tk

The website looks fine on the web-view, but when I view the website .tk website on mobile , the website looks zoomed out to some extent. While viewing the website with 000webhostapp in the domain name on mobile is a fine experience.

How to solve this issue ?
GitHub Link--> http://github.com/nvzard/Davisco-MUJ-Website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you aren't really performing a website redirect (permanent or temporary) but you are using an **iframe** element which is most likely the reason your website may not look properly.

I would recommend you to redirect your .tk permanently (301 redirect) to your actual website and choose to have the URL masked. This is the proper way and it will not affect users' experience.

Now, I also have noticed that you have quite a few files that are not loading into your website, including bootstrap.min.js and ie viewport workaround javascript file.

I would recommend you to edit the HTML file you have and point the following files to the correct path:

- ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css
- ie-emulation-modes-warning.js
- ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js
- bootstrap.min.js

If you are using Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, you can easily Inspect the website, switch to console and see the errors. You can find out how to do that by checking these sites:

**For Google Chrome:** https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

**For Mozilla Firefox:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console